# Is there a way to reverse only the numbers when I return a sql column ? (hebrew)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in a table the contains pseudo address - street-name and number.
The adress is in hebrew:
ביאליק **23**
But I would like to return the same address but only the number reversed:
ביאליק **32**
I'm not sure this has something to do about it - but the column is VARCHAR2(56) , NLS_CHARACTERSET IW8ISO8859P8

```
create table a (address VARCHAR2(56));

insert into  a (address) values ('ביאליק 23');

select 'return the full address but reverse only the numbers' from a;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the street address would always appear first, we can try using a combination of a regex substring operation along with the `REVERSE()` string function:

```sql
SELECT
    REVERSE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(address, '([0-9]+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)) || ' ' ||
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(address, '(.*) [0-9]+$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS new_address
FROM a;
```

Comment: I tried it, but it returned absoloutly nothing ...

Comment: I have edited my answer to now assume that the street number is occurring last.  You can try this updated version.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I believe one solved it

Comment: Store the street number as a separate column and reverse it.

Comment: Beware! REVERSE is undocumented and unsupported function (see list of available functions in Oracle 23, here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-B93F789D-B486-49FF-B0CD-0C6181C5D85C). It *exists* but there's no guarantee that Oracle will keep it in future database versions, so your code might just break.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the use of some string manipulation functinos like `substr()`, `instr()` and `reverse()`

Query:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(address, 0, INSTR(address, ' ') ) || REVERSE(SUBSTR(address, INSTR(address, ' ') + 1)) as reversed_address
  FROM a;
```

Output:

| REVERSED_ADDRESS |
| --- |
| בליק 32 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Mmgwl4lE)

If there is possibility of having number in middle of the string then below approach will be the appropriate one:

Query:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_REPLACE(address, '(\d+)', REVERSE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(address, '\d+'))) AS reserved_address
FROM
    a;
```

Output:

| RESERVED_ADDRESS |
| --- |
| ביאליק 32 |
| ADDR 87 SS |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h_-vNydT)

Answer (score 0):

This solved it,

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(address,'[^[:alpha:]]') || ' ' || reverse(regexp_replace(address, '[^[:digit:]]', '')) from a;
```

Thank you